# procmailrc and HTTP requests in Python not working

Tags: python, http

I am running in to an issue when making HTTP calls from the python script that is getting called from the .procmailrc file. Can you pls suggest an approach how to resolve it? I ran out of all options. The HTTP call works fine when the same script is ran from command line. 
Here are details:

.procmailrc content:
    DEFAULT=$HOME/Maildir/
    MAILDIR=$HOME/Maildir
    PMDIR=$HOME/.procmail
    LOGFILE=/home/prasad/log.'date +%y-%m-%d'
    SHELL=/bin/bash
    VERBOSE=YES

```
:0
| /usr/bin/python /home/prasad/test.py >>/tmp/py_log.txt
```

And it can make net connection when ran from command line.

Content of test.py:

```
url="http://server/book"
post_params = {
 'foo' : 'bar'
}

params = urllib.urlencode(post_params)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, params)
print "after urlopen"
json_response = json.loads(response.read())
```

It hangs at 'response = urllib2.urlopen(url, params)' and never see the print "after urlopen" call.

EDIT:
I just found permission error in the log file that procmail generating. The procmailrc is running under non root account. How to fix it?

```
procmail: Executing " /usr/bin/python /home/prasad/test.py  >>/tmp/py_log.txt"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/prasad/test.py", line 23, in <module>
  response = urllib2.urlopen(url, params)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
   return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
   response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
 '_open', req)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1190, in http_open
return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1165, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 13] Permission denied>
```

Comment: How is writing to /tmp require root permission?

Comment: Not a problem in writing to /tmp, but the problem is at the http access level. Like in these lines: File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1190, in http_open
return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1165, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 13] Permission denied>

Comment: Perhaps you need to somehow grant that user the ability to use sytem sockets? Could this be related to a firewall? Can the user write to the `/home/prasad` directory?

Comment: ah. i overlooked the ``>>`` sigh.

Comment: Yes, the user can write to the directory. Also running the script with the same user from command line works fine. Firewall is not a problem either as it can connect from command line without problem and tried turning it off too. Any other ideas?